# What does "|_|" mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I am learning how to connect database to Rust program. There something I don't quite understand:

```
PgConnection::establish(&database_url).unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
```

What does this expression mean? What does `|_|` mean?

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/what-are-pipes-and-underscores-doing-in-rust/14601

Comment: _"What does this expression mean?"_ - With apologies for pedantry, but in programming-languages the term "_expression_" [has a specific meaning](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements-and-expressions.html) - whereas if you want to point to some syntax or programming code construct you don't _grok_ you should say something like "What does this syntax mean?" or similar.

Comment: Related: [What does Rust's unary || (parallel pipe) mean?](/q/36988622/2189130)

Comment: In terms of its block syntax, Rust is highly inspired by Ruby.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ignoring the underscore `_` for now, some exposition is necessary:

### Closures and those pipe-characters `|`:

The term "closure" is effectively synonymous with terms like "lambda-function", "anonymous function", ["block"](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures/), "inline function expression", etc - and it basically means a function-defintion with *environment capture* semantics, so the closure can use variables declared in a parent scope.

Closures, like any other function, are going to need a parameter-list, and [Rust borrowed Ruby](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/influences.html)'s [use of pipes `|`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/83a3d13cb07c040a5e86ad4d7021b9c7482e5dbc/language/yield_spec.rb) to denote closures' parameter lists - this is in contrast to other popular languages like JavaScript and C# that opted to use normal parentheses with a "*fat arrow*" to denote a closure, e.g. `( x, y, z ) =>`.

[Rust's documentation has a section on their syntax for closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures.html) that I recommend people read.

By example, here is a quick comparison of semantically similar code that filters-out numbers greater-than-or-equal-to 5 from an input `bigArray` shown in JavaScript, C#, Ruby, and Rust:

```
// JavaScript:
const smallerArray = bigArray.filter( ( num ) => num < 5 );

// C#:
Int32[] smallerArray = bigArray.Where( num => num < 5 ).ToArray();
Int32[] smallerArray = bigArray.Where( ( Int32 num ) => num < 5 ).ToArray(); // With parameter-list parentheses and explicit parameter types.

// Ruby:
smallerArray = bigArray.select {|num| num < 5}

// Rust:
let smaller_array = big_array.into_iter().filter( |num| num < 5 )
```

Rust, just like JavaScript, C# and Ruby also supports multi-statement closures - the 4 examples above are all single-parameter, single-expression closures, while equivalent multi-statement-bodied closures have slightly expanded syntax:

```
// JavaScript:
const smallerArray = bigArray.filter( ( num ) => { return num < 5; } );

// C#:
Int32[] smallerArray = bigArray.Where( ( Int32 num ) => { return num < 5; } ).ToArray(); // You can also use the *very-old* `delegate( Int32 num ) { ... }` syntax.

// Ruby:
smallerArray = bigArray.select do |num|
    num < 5
end

// Rust:
let smaller_array = big_array.into_iter().filter( |num| { num < 5 } ); // Rust does not require a `return` statement here.
```

### The underscore `_`:

As for the underscore: Rust shares [Python's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) and [C#'s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) convention for using an underscore to denote a *discarded* or otherwise ignored parameter or local. Now you might wonder what the point of a discarded parameter is: why not just omit it entirely like in JavaScript? (e.g. `bigArray.filter( x => x < 5 )` and `bigArray.filter( ( x, idx ) => x < 5 )` and `bigArray.filter( ( x, idx, arr ) => x < 5 )` are all equivalent.

...well, JavaScript doesn't support function overloading: each function name resolves to a single function implementation, so omitting unused parameters isn't a problem. Now while Rust doesn't support function overloading either, it's still a very large and complex language that has many situations where you will need to explicitly declare a parameter that you don't use (strictly speaking, `_` represents an unbound identifier and you cannot use `_` as a variable).

The main use-case for naming a function parameter to `_` in Rust [is because it's a value annotated with the "`must_use`" attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/diagnostics.html#the-must_use-attribute) - but if you *really know* you don't need to use that (bound) parameter and you don't want to be bombarded with low-value compiler warnings about `must_use` values, then `_` is a handy solution.

Another use-cases of `_` is to declare that a call-site's return-value is being *willfully* discarded (so this syntax *signifies intent*), for example:

```rust
let _ = someFunctionThatReturnsAValue();
```

...whereas if you simply put `someFunctionThatReturnsAValue();` on its own line then anyone else reading the code, or a static-analysis tool, will think you absent-mindedly forgot to check `someFunctionThatReturnsAValue`'s return-value - but using `let _ = ...` makes it clear that *you really don't care* about the return value such that you don't want static-analysis tools dinging you.

---

So given `unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))`, what does `|_|` mean?

- `unwrap_or_else` [is a method of `std::result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else).
- `unwrap_or_else`'s parameter is a callback function [`op: FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). If the `result`  is-not-`Ok` then `op` will be invoked and `op`'s return-value becomes the end-result of the `unwrap_or_else` expression (or it panics... your call).

  - Crucially, the `op` function in `unwrap_or_else` accepts one (1) parameter which is the `E` error-value contained within the `result`.
  - In this case, the `panic!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))` expression doesn't use the inner error value at all (which I think is a bad idea) so the callback closure/function discards the value by using the `_` syntax.
- So **in conclusion**, `|_|` in `unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error")` means *"The argument of `unwrap_or_else` is an anonymous function accepting an `E` (error value)-typed parameter - buuuut we just don't care about it, so pretend it doesn't exist"*.

Comment: "Instead of being a conformist and using ( ) => like everyone else" besides the two languages you've mentioned, I can't think of any other programming language that uses `() =>` to denote lambdas. Haskell has `\ ->`, OCaml has `fun` or `function`, Python has `lambda :`, scheme has `(lambda () )`, Ruby has a similar pipe syntax, C++ has `[](){ }`, ...

Comment: Besides, closures in Rust have a single syntax, which is `|...| expr`. It's just that blocks `{ statement; statement; ...}` are also expressions, so if you want to have several statements, you have to use braces.

Comment: @BlackBeans Rust's pipe syntax is indeed taken from Ruby (https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/influences.html).

Comment: @jthulhu I've rewritten the more controversial parts of my answer to be more accurate - and to cite Ruby. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I ended up here while debugging a large Rust codebase (I conceptually know Rust but not idiomatically). My question is: why is it ok to throw away the error? I have this same code idiom (if there's an error throw the details away and panic with some meaningless string instead) repeated thousands of times in the code I'm looking at. It means for example that the test failures I'm attempting to debug print nothing useful except that the test failed, somewhere.

Comment: @DavidBoreham _"why is it ok to throw away the error?"_ - Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to discard/ignore an error object/value/enum as shown in this QA - because error objects usually contain helpful info (e.g. the called `PgConnection::establish` call in the OP's post fails with [a `ConnectionError` enum](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/prelude/enum.ConnectionError.html)) - however when writing _scratch code_ or when quickly prototyping something, then you won't want to spend time fleshing-out error-handling code that you know will never be invoked.

Comment: @DavidBoreham Though an acceptable reason to discard an error is when the called func will only fail for one particular reason and so there wouldn't be any useful info in the object worth dealing with - though I'l admit I struggle to think of any _good_ examples (instead of godawful examples...)